# Create one time popup with materialize css

Tags: html, css, materialize

Is there any way to evade jquery and make notification be shown only one time per browser ?

For example, goes to website, notification pops up and that is it, next time when user comes to site from same browser notification wont be showen to him.

I would mainly try to evade adding jquery just for that, so if anyone knows a way to do this with materializecss or some plain html i would be thankful.

Comment: Read about [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you trigger the notification?

You could do a basic localStorage check for example to "detect" if the notification has been displayed or not:

```
function foo() {

  const hasSeenNotification = window.localStorage.getItem('shown');
  if (!hasSeenNotification) {

    window.localStorage.setItem('shown', true);

    // show notification here
    // ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add cookies.

And then check is it is exists:

```
if (GetCookieShowMessageDocument('ShowPoPUP'))
{
  ...
}
```

Here is a sample:

```
 function GetCookieShowMessageDocument(c_name) {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }

    function SetCookieShowMessageDocument(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```

Comment: so you set it at first time and then just check it